# How to handle No Network connection using Retrofit 2.0 in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit, retrofit2, android-webservice

I am using **Retrofit 2.0** library in my android application by adding it into `build.gradle` file

```
// retrofit, gson
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

related code is given below

**ApiInterface.java**

```
public interface ApiInterface {
   @GET("contacts/")
   Call<ContactsModel> getContactsList();
}
```

**ApiClient.java**

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://myexamplebaseurl/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

Call<ContactsModel> call = apiService.getContactsList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactsModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ContactsModel> call, Response<ContactsModel> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                /*here is my data handling*/
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ContactsModel> call, Throwable t) {
            /*It is the request failure case, 
              I want to differentiate Request timeout, no internet connection and any other reason behind the request failure
            */
        }
    });
```

if we get status code as 4xx or 5xx even though `onResponse()` will called, so there we need handle that condition also.

Here my question is, How to differentiate reason for request failure i.e `onFailure()` by using Retrofit 2.0 in Android?

Answer (score 1):

> Here my question is, How to differentiate reason for request failure
>   by using Retrofit 2.0 in Android?

if you have a 4xx or 5xx error, `onResponse` is still called. There you have to check the response code of the code to check if everything was fine. E.g

```
if (response.code() < 400) {
```

in case of `No Network connection`, `onFailure` is called. There you could check the instance of the throwable. Typically an IOException

Comment: Thanks for reply. I agree with your point "4xx or 5xx error, onResponse is still called" and you mean to say If that exception is IOException Type then, is it "No Network connection" ?

Comment: indeed. Look the direct subclasses of IOException [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)

Comment: more than  "No Network connection" I would say, there were problems reaching the server out.

Comment: If the remote server is down or the device has no internet, in both situations you will get the `IOException`. how can we show the common  message "No Network connection" to the user. How can we  differentiate these two.

Comment: @Madhu you have to check the instance of IOExcepiton